# Hex codes in XSD string pattern

Tags: regex, xsd, hex

I have a XSD with the following string pattern for a particular type :

```
 [A-Z0-9a-z\-/'\?:\+&#x00C0;-&#x00D6;&#x00D8;-&#x00F6;&#x00F8;-&#x00FF;&#x0100;-&#x0137;&#x0139;-&#x0148;&#x014A;-&#x017E;&#x0386;&#x0388;-&#x038A;&#x038C;&#x038E;-&#x03A1;&#x03A3;-&#x03CE;&#x0401;-&#x040C;&#x040E;-&#x044F;&#x0451;-&#x045C;&#x045E;&#x045F;&#x046A;&#x046B;&#x0474;&#x0475;&#x0490;&#x0491; ]+
```

What does "-" mean in front of &#x00D6 for instance?

Subsidiary question, is the caracter "Ó" (D3 in hex) allowed by this XSD?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you posted the full code? Is it not `[A-Z0-9....]`?

Comment: I edited my first message.

Comment: `-` is a range forming operator inside a character class. Yes, `Ó` is matched.

Comment: OK, I don't really see what are the ranges in this XSD. There is a range from &# x 00D6 to which char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is in fact  the following

```
^[A-Z0-9a-z\-/'\?:\+À-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ķĹ-ňŊ-žΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ώЁ-ЌЎ-яё-ќўџѪѫѴѵҐґ ]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU9cU1/1)

In XSD, the pattern is anchored by default, hence `^` and `$` I used in the online tester (matching at the start/end of string).

The `-` creates ranges between the characters *in the Unicode table*. A range of `\u0000` till `\u0010` will match `\u0001`, `\u0002`, `\u0003` .. `\u0010` characters. Read about [**character classes** at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Use [this converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) to see the literal symbols and identify the hex codes.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew! Indeed, I see the ranges now. Hex codes were annoying me...